# Offload media to Amazon S3 + Cloudflare CDN + LE SSL + Siteground

Tags: amazon-s3, cloudflare

I'm encountering an issue which I would assume should be quite common but there doesn't seem to be a definitive answer or solution.

I am hosted with siteground and use Cloudflare as a CDN as it comes partnered with siteground (DNS managed by siteground not Cloudflare).

What Im wanting to do is:
1. Offload media to s3
2. Set up a subdomain 
3. Set up CNAME for subdomain to link to s3 bucket
4. Serve offloaded media via Cloudfoare CDN
5. Ensure SSL over entire process as it currently is blocking it due to a host name mismatch.

I found some discussions around this which advised I used the region specific s3 bucket url for the CNAME and change SSL to flexible on Cloudflare. This SSL change through my entire website into a too many redirects error, which is apparently a known issue.

I feel as though I've explored every forum topic and thread on this issue with no avail.

In this case, is the only solution to abandon cloudflare as my CDN and opt for Cloudfront by AWS? In which case, can Let's Encryot SSL certs be loaded onto AWS certificate manager?

Comment: Were you able to find the solution to this? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: @PythonEnthusiast no, I just ditched cloudflare and set it up through cloudfront. It all works very smoothly for me now, but it was a shame that I had to use Cloudfront instead. As for SSL, there's no trouble following the tutorial I followed by WP Offload Media.